# Symfony 5 > Display Roles as "human readable"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, user-roles, symfony-security

I want set up Symfony 5 to use "human readable" roles for display purposes. When displaying user information in TWIG I can use {{ user.roles[0] }}. However, this displays (for example) "**ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN**" (as is saved against the user in the database), but I would like it to display as "**Account Administrator**". With Symfony 3 where a user_roles table was used, there was a "role" and a "name" field, but this has been removed. Is it possible to accomplish this in Symfony 5 without having to define / include an array whenever I want to use this?

Comment: You can just write a twig extension for this.https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: @TrầnQuangSơn This is not only a problem in TWIG, I have user data that is retrieved via AJAX and populated on screen dynamically. The same issue applies to that data. A TWIG extension will therefor not solve the problem, as TWIG is done rendering at that point.

Comment: So in ajax request you can return a template in response, then get that html response append to the page

Comment: @TrầnQuangSơn This is exactly what I do not want to do - having to include a template in every response where I return users (or a user) in the AJAX response. I am looking for a way that I can update my USER model so that the returned model data shows the user role, as well as the "printable" name.

Comment: Do you have access to translations?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension twig and you have many solutions ...,
but for the solution that I see the simplest, just put a field on the entity and initialize it with the main role, so you will have the info on the api and twig, mailing ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

// ...

class User 
{
    public static $USER_ROLE_AS_HUMAN_READABLE_INDEX = [
        'ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN' => 'Account Administrator',
        'OTHER_ROLE' => 'Description',
        // ...
    ]

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    // without mapping ..
    private $roleHumanReadable
    // ...


    public  function __construct() {
       
       $this->initializeRoleHumanReadable();
   
    }


    public function getRoleHumanReadable():?string
    {
        return $this->roleHumanReadable;
    }



    public function initializeRoleHumanReadable():void
    {
        $rolePrincipal = $this->getRoles()[0] ?? null;

        if (!isset(static::$USER_ROLE_AS_HUMAN_READABLE_INDEX[$rolePrincipal])) {
            return;
        }

        $this->roleHumanReadable = static::$USER_ROLE_AS_HUMAN_READABLE_INDEX[$rolePrincipal];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity class seems like a reasonable place to put the list of roles, but I wouldn't add any constructors for such a simple feature.  Mine looks more like this.

```
namespace App\Entity;

class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    public const ROLE_NAMES = [
        'ROLE_USER' => 'User',
        'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Administrator',
    ];
    
    public function getPrettyRoles(): array
    {
        $all_roles = array_flip(self::ROLE_NAMES);
        $these_roles = $this->getRoles();

        return array_keys(array_intersect($all_roles, $these_roles));
    }
}
```